# Unable to Access Local Host From Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, uvicorn

## Problem

I have two Docker containers:

- a server ran with `fastapi;uvicorn`
- a client sending a `GET` request to `http://0.0.0.0`

The server seems to work just fine as bashing `curl -X GET http://0.0.0.0` works as expected. However, my docker client seems unable to get access.

After building the client container (files below), when running `docker run -it --name app_client_container app_client:latest` I receive the following error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: Errno 111 Connection refused'))

## Setup

My project looks like this

```
|- client.Dockerfile
|- client.py
|- client_req.txt
|- server.Dockerfile
|- server.py
|- server_req.txt
```

**Client**

```py
# client.Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /srv
WORKDIR /srv
ADD client_req.txt /srv/client_req.txt
RUN pip install -r client_req.txt

ADD . /srv
CMD python /srv/client.py

# client.py
import json
import requests
import traceback

try:
    response = requests.get('http://0.0.0.0', timeout=5)
    print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4))
except Exception as e:
    print('Connection could not be established :(')
    print('Here is more information:')
    traceback.print_exc()

# client_req.txt
requests
```

**Server**

```py
# server.Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /srv
ADD server_req.txt /srv/server_req.txt
RUN pip install -r server_req.txt

EXPOSE 80

ADD . /srv
CMD uvicorn server:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --reload

# server.py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

# server_req.txt
fastapi
uvicorn
```

Comment: Any time you have multiple containers that need to communicate I _strongly_ recommend using Docker Compose, or a similar tool. It makes inter-container communication much simpler.

Comment: @Chris I'll look into it

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address that means “everywhere”; it usually only makes sense to tell servers what interfaces to listen on, not as a target for outbound HTTP requests.  When your client makes that call, where do you expect it to go?

Comment: @DavidMaze I was just following [this tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/) and my idea was to switch to `127.0.0.1` once I got it up and running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running the client with `docker run ... --net=host ...`

Although the server exposes `:80` to the host, the host's network is not, by default, available to other containers; i.e. the host's `:80` is not available inside other (including the client) containers.

Alternatively, you may:

- reference the host via its DNS within the container;
- create a docker network and bind both containers to it (thereby also using container names to reference)
- or -- somewhat equally to the previous -- use Docker Compose.

Comment: Thanks, the `--net=host` flag solved it. I'll still look into the alternatives though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [default docker bridge network.](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-the-default-bridge-network)

Set the IP address to: **172.17.0.1** (for mac it is docker.for.mac.host.internal)
This should work:

```
response = requests.get('http://172.17.0.1', timeout=5)
```

Comment: I works but I don't understand why I cant use say `requests.get('http://localhost:4001/auth')`

Comment: Let's have two running containers c1 and c2. If you are inside c1 then calling GET HTTP://localhost:4001 is pointing to itself, i.e. container c1. The c1 can communicate with an external world (your system and c2) only using a bridge network.